# How to have click event on everything inside a div,except one particular div and its child node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I'm appending a div to another div `.foobar` on click event.

**HTML**

```
<div class='foobar'>
    
    <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.foobar {
    padding: 20px;
    width:400px;
    height:800px;
    background: yellow;
}

.run {
    background:blue;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.foobar').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target !== this) return;
    var posX = $(this).offset().left, posY = $(this).offset().top;

    $('.foobar').append('<div style="top:'+(e.pageY - posY)+'px;left:'+ (e.pageX - posX)+'px;" class="run"><p>child</p></div>');
});
```

I want that I can append div, whenever I click on anywhere div `.foobar` except the appended div and its child node.

Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eaVzx/440/)

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the click happened in the run element

```js
$('.foobar').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('.run').length) return;
  var posX = $(this).offset().left,
    posY = $(this).offset().top;

  $('.foobar').append('<div style="top:' + (e.pageY - posY) + 'px;left:' + (e.pageX - posX) + 'px;" class="run"><p>child</p></div>');
});
```

```css
.foobar {
  padding: 20px;
  background: yellow;
}
span {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='foobar'>
  <span>child</span>
</div>
```